# ConfigParser and global variables

Tags: python, configuration, global-variables, config

I have a python file that calls a function in another directory.
I would like to use the config variable **DATA_DIR** in the function directly without importing configuration at each time.

The main file looks like this :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read('static.cfg')
global __DATA_DIR__
__DATA_DIR__ = config.get('Directories', '__DATA_DIR__')

from src.directory import file

file.function()
```

The function looks like this :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def function():

    global __DATA_DIR__
        print (__DATA_DIR__)
```

The configuration file looks like this :

```
[Directories]
__DATA_DIR__=/directorie/to/config.cfg
```

When executing the first main program, I had this error :

> NameError: global name '**DATA_DIR**' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Why not pass the config argument to the function. This would need confirmation but I would imagine that only the read method actually reads and parses the actual file, and the config.get method only gives you data from an internal datastructure, so passing the config object and doing a config.get inside the function would be pretty efficient.

so :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import ConfigParser
from src.directory import file

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read('static.cfg')
file.function( config )
```

and in your file :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def function( cfg ):
    print ( cfg.get("__DATA_DIR__") )
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are importing your function, you should pass in your `__DATA_DIR__` variable to it:

```
from src.directory import file
file.function(__DATA_DIR__)

#your other file
def function(data):
    print (data)
```

Comment: No other method to declare a global variable once for all ?

Comment: @4m1nh4j1, Possibly, but its definitely going to be understandable. The best way would be to pass in relevant data to functions that need it.

Comment: My config file will contain more than 10 variable, passing arguments will be long a each time. Otherwise, using ConfigParser in each function could be a solution. But I was looking for simpler methods. Thanks anyway.